# Azure Cloud Attempting to bind SSL Certificate Timeout

Tags: ssl, azure, cloud

I have configured SSL for my cloud service as per

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuredevsupport/archive/2010/02/24/how-to-install-a-chained-ssl-certificate.aspx

But when I start my application locally it still looks for a different cert with thumbprint F8ACE24A36F93B006BFAF495F6C14FB827AC61A3 which I can find on certificate store and is issued to 127.0.0.1.

I am wondering why my SSL certificate is not used and why attempt to bind to the default cert is timing out.

-Jalal

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your cert is in the correct store i.e. "Local Machine" and NOT current user
2. Make sure you are running your cloud service in the emulator
3. Make sure that IUSR and NETWORK SERVICE have access to the private keys for the cert - Start >> Run >> MMC, then add in Certificate snap-in for "Local Computer" - find the cert and right click, All Tasks >> Manage Private Keys